# layout engine for .net with html5 support and such

Tags: .net, layout, browser, webkit, geckofx

I am looking for a layout engine such as geckofx or webkit.net, which is up to date! the two I've named are outdated for a long time! is there any alternative or even a update for the ones named?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the two i've named are outdated for a long time!

Good news. GeckoFX is alive and well here: https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/. Be aware that each new version of Firefox leads to a new fork of GeckoFX, so you have to decide which version you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Also remember that HTML5 is not formally designed yet - no browser is 100% compliant as no one has fuilly agreed the properties of HTML5.